# Is it okay to assign the value of the DetailsList's setkey property to a static string?

Tags: reactjs, selection, fluent, fluent-ui, detailslist

I am using Fluent UI DetailsList component.

I have a custom parent component that has a `DetailsList` component as a child component. This parent component is used in many places, and the  `items` props passed to the `DetailsList` component are many and varied.

When using this parent component, I want to use the DetailsList's setkey property to retain the selection information even if an unexpected re-render occurs.

Even if this parent component is used in many places, would it be better to set the property value of `setkey` to a consistent string value?

Or is it more effective to reduce unexpected bugs or side-effects by using the `setkey` property value that combines the unique information of the delivered `items` props?

Also, is there another way other than using the `setkey` property value to maintain the selection information of the `DetailsList`?

Answer (score 0):

They do this themselves in several documentation pages so I would say it's fine.